Existe un software de maquinas virtuales que funcione bien en MacOS con Chip M1 (arquitectura ARM64)?
He estado buscando y existen varios software para montar maquinas virtuales de diversos sistemas operativos en MacOS, cuando tenía un Mac con Chip intel usaba el virtual box y funcionaba de maravilla.. pero ahora con el chip arm64 (M1) ya ando medio perdido, ¿alguien ha tenido una buena experiencia con algún programa que le haya dado buenos resultados?
Estoy descargando uno llamado UTM Virtual machines ... pero parece que no anda muy bien... al menos en los comentarios eso dice.
Gracias!
